# My data will not show unless there is a match between the two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

My problem is that this query only works if the MainRule table has an ID that matches the Table1 table.  I need the query to work even if the MainRule table does not have a matching ID. The records in Table1 should show even if there isn't a matching record(s) in the MainRule table.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT  Person, OrderNum, Name, County, SubmitDate, Days1, 
        SUM(Date_Diff) - 1 AS [Number of Uncleared Days] 
  From
     (SELECT D1.RecordID AS Person, D3.[case no] AS OrderNum, 
             D3.FullName AS Name, D3.County, D3.[SignedDate] AS SubmitDate,
                  DATEDIFF(d, D3.[SignedDate], D3.closedate) AS Days1,
                  DATEDIFF(DAY, [HoldDate],
                  (SELECT TOP 1 [StatusDate]
                     FROM [MainRule] D2
                    WHERE D2.Status = 'Cleared' 
                      AND D1.RecordID = D2.RecordID 
                      AND D1.StatusDate < D2.StatusDate)) AS [Date_Diff]
        FROM [MainRule] AS D1 INNER JOIN table1 AS D3 ON D3.ID = D1.RecordID
       WHERE D1.Status = 'UnCleared') SubQ 
WHERE (SubmitDate BETWEEN '10/01/2017' and '10/17/2017')
GROUP BY Person, OrderNum, Name, County, SubmitDate, Days1
```

Comment: Then you should use Table1 as the root of your query and left join to MainRule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems: the `INNER JOIN` (as explained by the other answer), and the `WHERE D1.Status = 'UnCleared'`.

No matter what your join is, that `WHERE` clause is going to exclude rows with no matching MainRule row.

Try something like `WHERE D1.Status = 'UnCleared' OR D1.Status IS NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT  Person, OrderNum, Name, County, SubmitDate, Days1, 
        SUM(Date_Diff) - 1 AS [Number of Uncleared Days] 
  From
     (SELECT D1.RecordID AS Person, D3.[case no] AS OrderNum, 
             D3.FullName AS Name, D3.County, D3.[SignedDate] AS SubmitDate, 
                  DATEDIFF(d, D3.[SignedDate], D3.closedate) AS Days1, 
                  DATEDIFF(DAY, [HoldDate],                                                      
                  (SELECT TOP 1 [StatusDate]
                     FROM [MainRule] D2
                    WHERE D2.Status = 'Cleared' 
                      AND D1.RecordID = D2.RecordID 
                      AND D1.StatusDate < D2.StatusDate)) AS [Date_Diff]
        FROM table1 AS D3
        LEFT JOIN [MainRule] AS D1 ON D3.ID = D1.RecordID
       WHERE D1.Status = 'UnCleared')  SubQ 
WHERE (SubmitDate BETWEEN '10/01/2017' and '10/17/2017')
GROUP BY Person, OrderNum, Name, County, SubmitDate, Days1
```

This way you will get all the rows from `MainRule` (the left table), even if there is no matching row in the other table `table1`.

You should read more about the difference between join types:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Actually, I need it to be the other way around.  I need rows from table1, even if there are no matching rows in the MainRule table.

Comment: @tnbumbray so switch the two tables in the query.

Comment: I have tried that and it's still not working.  I know there is data in table1 because when I remove the middle sub-query I get data.

Comment: @tnbumbray Please edit your question with some sample from both the tables.

Comment: This is true, but the `WHERE D1.Status = 'UnCleared'` is also a problem. See my answer.